# What mistake am I making with syntax?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have to make a code to calculate pay/what type of work you did (part-time, overtime, etc.)
My code is this:

```
hours=int(input("How many hours did you work?"))
rate=int(input("What is your hourly rate?"))
bonusr=int(input("What is your bonus rate?"))
normaltotal=rate*hours
bonus=rate*bonusr*(hours-40)
pay+bonus=normaltotal+bonus 
if hours<32:
  print("You worked part-time")
  print(normaltotal)
elif hours>32 and <=40:
  print("You worked Full-Time")
  print(normaltotal)
elif hours>40:
  print("You worked over-time")
  print(pay+bonus)
```

Im getting a syntax error for "elif hours>32 and <=40" and I'm not sure why

Would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the 'and' logic, it will operate the clauses separately. To use it properly, you need to state 'hours' twice:

```
hours=int(input("How many hours did you work?"))
rate=int(input("What is your hourly rate?"))
bonusr=int(input("What is your bonus rate?"))
normaltotal=rate*hours
bonus=rate*bonusr*(hours-40) if hours > 40 else 0
pay_plus_bonus=normaltotal+bonus 
if hours<32:
  print("You worked part-time")
  print(normaltotal)
elif hours>32 and hours<=40:
  print("You worked Full-Time")
  print(normaltotal)
elif hours>40:
  print("You worked over-time")
  print(pay_plus_bonus)
```

Comment: Any issue with `pay+bonus=normaltotal+bonus `?  Or with `bonus=rate*bonusr*(hours-40)` when we don't know if hours > 40?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that yesterday. You cannot use “+” in variable names, and you need to ensure that hours is greater than 40 or else the bonus will go negative. Please see my edited answer.